# Execute Javascript using Node in terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js

[I know](https://www.codecademy.com/article/what-is-node) that

> Node.js allows to write JavaScript code that runs directly in a
> computer process itself instead of in a browser

Reading this, I try to open my terminal and run:

```bash
console.log('hello')
```

but I get **zsh: unknown file attribute**.
The same happens with `node console.log('hello')`.

If I instead create a file `hello.js` and put the console inside it and then I run:

```bash
node src/hello.js
```

it works. Why? What am I missing?

Sorry for the (maybe) stupid question

Comment: `node --eval "console.log('hello');"`

Comment: You have to provide the code as an argument. Otherwise `zsh` will going to try to parse it, and this won't do anything good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `console.log('hello')` is being evaluated by your shell (`zsh`) before running the command and it has no idea what `console.log('hello')` is. You could use the  `-e` or `--eval` arguments.

```
$ node -e "console.log('hello')"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using linux, first type `node` It will profile for you a REPL. which is essecially the excution terminal.

You can also do the same on windows